# AFNetworking returns no connection despite internet connectivity

Tags: ios, objective-c, afnetworking

I'm using AFNetworking to determine whether the user has an internet connection.  It returns false on both wifi and 4G LTE and I have checked to make sure they're operational. 
  I have the following code:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad{
 [[AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager] startMonitoring];   

     if ([self connected])
        [self doSomething];
     else
        [self noConnection];
}

- (BOOL)connected {
     NSLog(@"This returns 0 %hhd", [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable);
     return [AFNetworkReachabilityManager sharedManager].reachable;
}

-(void)noConnection{
    UIAlertView *alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"No Internet!"
                                                message:@"Sorry, but you don't have an internet      connection at this time.  Please try again later."
                                               delegate:self
                                      cancelButtonTitle:@"OK"
                                      otherButtonTitles:nil];
     [alert show];

 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a solution using `AFNetworking` but using [sample code from apple](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html)

Once you have [downloaded](https://developer.apple.com/Library/ios/samplecode/Reachability/Introduction/Intro.html) and imported `Reachbility.m` and `Reachbility.h`  files

create a helper function:

```
-(BOOL)isConnected{
  Reachability *reachability = [Reachability reachabilityForInternetConnection];
  NetworkStatus networkStatus = [reachability currentReachabilityStatus];

  return !(networkStatus == NotReachable);    
}
```

Then use it

```
if([self isConnected]){
 //connected!
}
else{
  //not connected to internet!
}
```

---

**Very important**

If your project is not using arc

- go to target >
- Build Phase >
- double click the Reachability file
- add `-fno-objc-arc`

Hope this helps

Comment: Thank you.  Your code does work, but I am curious as to why AFNetworking has worked for me for >1 month and now in the last couple of days all of a sudden it always returns false (even when Apple's reachability returns true).

Comment: Sorry i dont know this project, if you really care i can try to checkout this project if i can replicate this? Did you make any changes the last couple of days?

Comment: none.  AFNetworking is used extensively throughout my project and if it makes internal checks for connectivity before carrying out operations such as HTTP Requests, then I'm in a lot of trouble...